# How to make use of pubring.gpg and secring.gpg

Tags: pgp

I just found my pubring.gpg and secring.gpg files, which I created for experimenting purposes years ago. I also know, in ascii, my public key. Because I can't remember how I generated my keys and what program I used, I actually don't know how to make use of these files. I remember my passphrase as well.

So, how can I make use of these files? Is there a concise guide for this? Is there a convenient GUI program under windows to handle these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can install gpg (Gnu Privacy Guard) and then drop those two files into the directory where gpg stores them by default.  In XP this is C:\Documents and Settings\UserProfile\Application Data\gnupg.  I believe I've moved my keys to a different machine using this method.

Have a look at [this](https://www.glump.net/howto/cryptography/practical-introduction-to-gnu-privacy-guard-in-windows) tutorial, It should get you started.

Comment: Seems the tutorial has moved to this URL: https://www.glump.net/howto/cryptography/practical-introduction-to-gnu-privacy-guard-in-windows but it didn't auto-redirect me.